# GROUP BY function not work

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

After update wamp php 5.6 and windows 10..., GROUP BY function not work, on windows 7 and previous wamp work fine. Are mistake in code or wamp or windows or.., else?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user JOIN messages ON userID = usertwo WHERE userone = $user GROUP BY usertwo ORDER BY MAX(date) DESC LIMIT 10";
                 $result = $con->query($sql);

                 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                 // output data of each row
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

---not working

But without GROUP BY and ()MAX work correctly

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user JOIN messages ON userID = usertwo WHERE userone = $user  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10";
                 $result = $con->query($sql);

                 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                 // output data of each row
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you now on?

Comment: you can not use * with group by

Comment: what is result do you want ? and show your sample table data

Comment: That really doesn't matter, it's because of the mysql option ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Comment: Same code before work on windows 7, and wamp php 5.5.. MySQL version - 5.7.14,  * with group by before work fine?

Comment: Order by and group by are backwards? Swap them. ? Also select the columns you want rather than `Select *`

Comment: Thank you, you are best, in new php 5.6 you must select the columns, not any more use *   :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, you are best, in new php 5.6 you must select the columns, not any more use * , not work lake in previous versions...

$sql = "SELECT userID, firstname, lastname FROM user JOIN messages ON userID = usertwo WHERE userone = $user GROUP BY usertwo ORDER BY MAX(date) DESC LIMIT 10";
                     $result = $con->query($sql);

```
                 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                 // output data of each row
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

thanks to: Farkie, krishn patel...